# Initiate data with redux better approach

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-thunk

hello guys I am trying to  fetch initial data for `redux` store from given `api` !

here is my first approach from using `store.dispatch`:

```
import { createStore, applyMiddleware, compose } from "redux";
import thunk from "redux-thunk";
import reducer from "./reducer";
import { fetchNews } from "./actions";

const store = createStore(
    reducer,
    compose(
        applyMiddleware(thunk),
        window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__ &&
            window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__()
    )
);

store.dispatch(fetchNews());

export default store;
```

and second approach is dispatching action from the component lifecycle method like this:

```
import React from "react";
import axios from "axios";
import InfiniteScroll from "react-infinite-scroller";
import { useSelector, useDispatch } from "react-redux";
import New from "./New";
import { fetchNews } from "../store/actions";

const Main = () => {
    const news = useSelector(state => state.news);
    const dispatch = useDispatch();
    React.useEffect(() => {
        dispatch(fetchNews());
    }, [dispatch]);
    return (
        <>
            {news.length > 0 ? (
                news.map(data => (
                    <New key={data.id} subTitle={data.created_at}>
                        {data.title}
                    </New>
                ))
            ) : (
                <p>News not found</p>
            )}
        </>
    );
};
```

OK both method works but  i really want to know what is the better approach here or is there any other better method! thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second one. The file in which you create the store should always be all about creating the store and exporting it as is.

By the way, on your useEffect, try removing the dispatch from the variables array:

```
React.useEffect(() => {
  dispatch(fetchNews());
}, []);
```

This way it will fetch the data on component mount, just like `ComponentDidMount`.

Comment: That will generate a warning for missing dependency `dispatch`.

Comment: While eslint might generate the warning, it doesn't make sense to put dispatch there, since its a constant and will never change.

Comment: OK but if i have a lot of data to fetch for different components i need to call every time each method from the related component ! i can use `store.dispatch` for faster approach?

Comment: I know. [We can omit since React guarantees `dispatch` to be **static**. But it also **doesn’t hurt** to specify them](https://overreacted.io/a-complete-guide-to-useeffect/)

Comment: @adel You should use `dispatch` in every component that uses API data. Don't forget, you might want to get the data at some parent component, and then pass it down to other relevant components by props.

Comment: @SagiRika using global store you can access data from every component! but the point is fetching a lot of data using store.dispatch is faster then using each component lifecycle method or i can create a HOC ?

Comment: Dispatching actions on component life cycle methods is the right way to go. You can also use a HOc, but I don't see why you'd want to do that.

Answer (score 5):

Dispatching action from the component lifecycle method is the recommended approach and is what should be followed in order to maintain the separation of concern design on which Redux is based on please check the attached image.[image: Redux Principles]

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't say dispatching from component lifecycle is the recommended approach , it certainly is used by many developers, but it couples in you component with data fetching (is that a good idea) ? Or should your component not know about how data is fetched and just consume it in some way. Your choice.

You could  use your own custom middleware to send the request.
With that approach you have greater flexibility , you could dispatch actions like type:LOADING_DATA and any others depending on setting state while loading your data. Once the data is returned dispatch other action(s) which could be handled by other custom middleware(s) to normalise data etc and finally send it to your reducer.

This approach is described very well in https://leanpub.com/thinking-in-Redux  or https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JUuic7mEs-s

I personally liked his ideas and perhaps you would find them useful.